# Is Play2.5 session cookie encrypted?

Tags: scala, session, cookies, playframework

I'm starting to learn Play framework with Scala and I'm trying to set the session cookie.

I have the **play.crypto.secret** config set and also the settings for the cookie like this

```
play.http {
   session {  
    httpOnly = true   
    domain = "localhost"
  }
}
```

Is it normal that I see the content of the cookie in the console without problems?

for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in official Play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret#The-Application-Secret), **play.crypto.secret** is used for signing session cookies and CSRF tokens. That's means that you will see cookie values on a client side, but they will be encrypted with the **secret key**.

Comment: but I see the values as plain text ... look on the picture I've posted i see the USER.ID.getname=123 ... so the value is not encrypted by default

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Here is what on of the PlayFramework committers say about the encryption of cookies and sessions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508195/play-framework-security-issue-regarding-cookies-and-sessions
I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

No, the cookie is not encrypted. It is signed, meaning that part of the cookie (or a separate cookie) contains a signature value calculated using the cookie value itself and the secret key.